# How to stop DialogFragment replaying Enter animation on resume

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I've created a DialogFragment that pops up over my Android app. I've overridden onActivityCreated as shown in examples and it looks like this:

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(arg0: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(arg0)
        if (showsDialog) {
                dialog?.window?.attributes?.windowAnimations = R.style.AnimationEnterExitFromRight
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
```

The Dialog enter animation has it sliding into place from the right edge of the screen. My problem is, if I minimize my app when the dialog is open and then return to the app, the dialog replays it's enter animation.  Is there a way to keep this animation from replaying? I've tried watching the dialogFragments lifecycle and it's not getting recreated, so I'm having a hard time figuring out WHY it replays the enter animation. One solution that works, but seems kludgy to me is I can alter the animation property onPause like this:

```
    override fun onPause() {
        dialog?.window?.attributes?.windowAnimations = R.style.AnimationNoOpen // Kludgy fix to keep enter animation from happening a second time
        super.onPause()
    }
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you done is already the right solution. Animation is managed by Window Composer and if the animation is triggered on Resume, then the only solution is to unset Window's Animation attribute.